# How to use bootstrap cards next to each other?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using 'class="card-group"' in bootstrap to make four cards to appear next to each other or to appear together in somethings like a row but i can not make it.

Comment: Post the code in the question please!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just add `.card {display:inline-block;}` to make them display in a line.

This is the official way according to the docs: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/#card-columns

Comment: What's the problem with this answer?

Comment: I have edited the answer and upvotes you as you posted the official answer :)

Answer (score 20):

You can also use bootstrap's grid, make a row and divide it, example :

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">Card 1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">Card 2</div>
</div>
```

See here for more details on this: [Grid system - Bootstrap](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/)

Comment: The answer is written already, making a row and dividing into columns, the link was put as a syntax reference, it wasn't a link only answer

Comment: Done, there's no need to be this rude , or to give it a -1, thanks anyway!